# NetBeans J2ME File Browser emulator sample files

Tags: java, netbeans, mobile, java-me, filepath

I'm building a J2ME application to read txt file. I use NetBeans FileBrowser plugin to build this appliation.

My problem: When i run my application in emulator, file browser only list folder tree as below:

```
root1
  + photos
  + private
```

and there are no file in these folders.

Here my question is, How can i add files to these folders for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look on the following file path. you can add the files on that file path for testing.

> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\username\j2mewtk\2.5.2\appdb\DefaultColorPhone\filesystem\root1\photos
> ```

Comment: Thanks, in my computer the path is: C:\Documents and Settings\username\javame-sdk\3.0\work\8\appdb\filesystem\root1